# Button after listview crashing the app--- XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I dont know why but i cant get my button to show up after the listview. It does show fine in eclipse-graphical layout but when i launch the emulator the program crashes... here is my xml code and if i move the button above the listview everything is OK. Any ideas? point me in the right direction please...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTeam1Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTeam2Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvVVTEST"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="tvVVTEST" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTeam1Score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTeam2Score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/tlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bNewRound"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bTest" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bNewRound"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="New Round" />
```

Comment: program crashes but any exception log please.

Comment: try with layout_weight=1 on your listview, then the button should popup. Why it crashes I dont know, post your log.

Comment: added the layout_weight=1 nothing changed i see the button fine in eclipse... kind of new... I dont see anything in logcat or the Error Log where am I looking for the exception log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    </RelativeLayout>       

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you changed it to linearlayout and added weight to the listview works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use `RelativeLayout` in such complex markup. Use `LinearLayout` instead as **baya** described. `RelativeLayout` is good when you want your widgets to lie on each other, for example dvd_box template and movie's cover on it.

And also if you use `LinearLayout` distribute it's space between it's children using `android:layout_weight`. It's realy useful and clear during reading your code if you express it in percentage terms.

Comment: just switched it to linearlayout and added weight to the listview works like a charm!!! :)