# How to fix Footer at bottom when using including different layouts in a single layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an Android application using android sdk v 2.1. In one page i am merging different layouts like headers, footer , list views etc.
My code is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <com.myapp.LogoBarActivity
                android:id="@+id/logobarLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    <include layout="@layout/header_2"/>    
    <include layout="@layout/header_3"/>

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

    <include layout="@layout/list_footer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But the problem is that bottom buttons (layout="@layout/list_footer") are not displaying when listview crossing the screen. I want to scroll listview between
 layout="@layout/header_3" and  layout="@layout/list_footer"  and all layout should be fixed on screen. Please guide me.

Comment: refer the following post..

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308983/button-after-listview-crashing-the-app-xml/8309134#8309134][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the RelativeLayout to get what you want . Your XML Code will be something like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <com.myapp.LogoBarActivity android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
                android:id="@+id/logoBar"
                android:id="@+id/logobarLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    <include layout="@layout/header_2" android:id="@+id/header2"  android:layout_below="@+id/logoBar"/>    
    <include layout="@layout/header_3" android:id="@+id/header3"  android:layout_below="@+id/header2"/>

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
              android:layout_below="@+id/header3"/>

    <include layout="@layout/list_footer" 
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:id="@+id/footer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Exactly like this. Except that you need to put the `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` to allow scrolling.

Comment: Also, remove the `+` from `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above`

Comment: Thank for your reply but I have tried this code already. When i am using this code then footer display at bottom and list view cover remaining whole screen by overriding header_3 at top and logo-bar and header_2 do not display on screen. In simple this disturb whole layout.

Comment: you want to display your list between the header3 and the footer,  and the code i gived above do exactly this , 
@iturki : i think you can't have a ListView inside of a ScrollView , i've already tried this and it gives an error , that's why i've used the relativeLayout , and i think there is one way to do that  , he should try to inflate the footer after the list is displayed on his layout

Comment: @Houcine i have already tried to inflate the footer but this will show footer at the end of list view. It will not fix footer at bottom. So it do not resolve my problem.

Comment: you want to fix the footer at the bottom of your screen , and your list will scroll between your header 3 and the footer ? ( if yes, soo the Code above is correct ) , if not , tell me what do you want exaclty plz 
@iturki : if you already try it , so add some link to  an example :) that will be appreciated ;)

Comment: @iturki : about the + in layout_below ...etc, it is not necessary to delete it , because sometimes, we want to put a view above another view which is not declared yet on our xml file , so it is preferable to use the sign + to avoid this problem, if i delete the + , it will give an error : the resource @id/footer is not resolved :)

Comment: @Houcine Thanks for your reply. I exactly want to scroll list between header3 and footer. Your code is correct. I also think it should run properly but not working. I am surprising why this is disturbing my layouts as i discussed above.

Comment: i think that there is something wrong with your includes ?? , plz add a screenCapture of what you got , so i can get ideas to resolve your problem , and to make sure that the code above is working fine, try just to modify your includes with textViews ( just for test ) ,  and see the result OK ? ;)

Comment: @ Houcine Actually my all included layouts are overwrite to previous one and starting from Top-Left corner. This seems like FrameLayout and list view is also scrolling over footer so it is not display. What should i do?

Comment: @ManojAgarwal : can you upload your project so i could verify your code and fix the problem for you ?? , because , i don't understand why it overdraw your list and footer like a framelayout , one explication is that the Identifients of your includes are not correct , so the compiler doesn't know where to positionne a view ( above , below ..etc  ) ,

Comment: @Houcine thanks. actually my list view and footer are not overdraw like frame-layout. These are logo-bar, header2,header3 and list-view which are overdrawn like frame-layout.

Comment: @ManojAgarwal : so just verify the Ids of each one of them , and verify the android:layout_below attribut of each one of ( header2 and header3 )  ; header2 should be below logoBar, and the header3 should be below the header2

Comment: Glad to hear it , so accept the answer as a final answer for you question, so others can get help from it :)